# Python open() gives "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:", but the file exists

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to read all the files in a directory and append the text in them into a list but I get the error in the header. However, the file actually exists. My code is:

```
pos_lines = []
train_pos_path = r'C:\Users\Halid\Desktop\nlp_p5\nlp_dir2\TRAIN\posTr'
# print(os.listdir(train_pos_path))
for filename in os.listdir(train_pos_path):
    with open(filename, "r",encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            pos_lines.append(line)
```

The path is the absolute path of the directory and `print(os.listdir(train_pos_path))` gives the list of the files under that directory. However, I can't open the files in it and it gives me the error I mentioned. My code I'm trying to run is in **"C:\Users\Halid\Desktop\nlp_p5"**. Does anybody know why I'm getting this error and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified an absolute path to the directory, `r'C:\Users\Halid\Desktop\nlp_p5\nlp_dir2\TRAIN\posTr'`. You then proceeded to list all files with their filenames, receiving `A`, `B`, `C`, ...

However, `A`, `B`, `C`, ... are not located in the directory you're running your python script.
Try calling

```
os.chdir(train_pos_path)
```

before calling the `for loop`.

Another solution would be to prepend each path with `train_pos_path`:

```
train_pos_path = r'C:\Users\Halid\Desktop\nlp_p5\nlp_dir2\TRAIN\posTr'

for filename in os.listdir(train_pos_path):
    with open(os.path.join(train_pos_path, filename), "r",encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            pos_lines.append(line)
```

The key takeaway from this is the fact that `os.listdir(directory)` returns just the names as seen from the `directory`, not their absolute paths.